# ACF meta key field displays Array when field is of "relationship" type in post grid plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In wordpress I have a custom post type (generated through the ACF plugin) of job offers which include several text fields (meta_key values) which the plugin "post grid pro" will display no problem. However, I have one field which is the agency that posted the job offer.

This is a **relationship** field and whenever I add this meta_key to the list of fields to display within each block of my grid it displays simply "Array".

I have tried creating my own shortcode to display this field but alas, this does not work.

There is a page in the site, written by one of the original developers, which lists the job offers. They have managed to display the title of the job agency in php with:

```
<?= get_field("agence")[0]->post_title ?>
```

I would like to be able to either write my own shortcode to display the agency title or somehow dynamically create a new meta_key for each job offer which contains automatically the name of the agency derived from the relationship field "agence".

Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the relationalship ACF field type, use the one called "[Post Object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/)". As long as you don't enable "Select multiple values?" option this will only return a single post object.

[This post](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/post-object-vs-relationship-which-should-i-use/) lists the difference between the two field types. Basically, they both return post objects, but they have slightly different options, and relationship fields always returns the result in an array. You could technically use the relationship field and set the minimum and maximum number of posts to 1, but the post object field is the most appropriate one to use when you only want a single post.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, in the end I gave up and created a template which copied the list created on the other page then adapted it to a grid with css then inserted it on the front page using a plugin.